# OBJECT_NOT_FOUND when trying to getServingUrl of an image stored in GCS

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, google-cloud-storage

I have written a Servlet where I am reading an image from `blobstore`, another image from GCS and then after applying a composite on both these images I am storing the composite image back in GCS.

My code works well till here.

After that, when I am trying to get the serving url for the composite image, I am getting an `OBJECT_NOT_FOUND`.

Just to experiment I manually uploaded a image in GCS and gave all the necessary permissions. Added the serviceaccount as OWNER and gave READ access to All users. And then again I am just trying to get the serving url. Following is my code:-

```
BlobKey newImageKey = blobstoreService.createGsBlobKey(gcsPath);
//log.severe("GCS PATH: " + gcsPath + " BlobKey: " + newImageKey);

ServingUrlOptions options = ServingUrlOptions.Builder.withBlobKey(newImageKey);
String profilePicLink = imgService.getServingUrl(options);
```

I also tried the below code:-

```
ServingUrlOptions options = ServingUrlOptions.Builder.withGoogleStorageFileName(gcsPath);
String profilePicLink = imgService.getServingUrl(options);
```

And in both the cases this is the error that I am getting:

> /controller javax.servlet.ServletException:
>   java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: OBJECT_NOT_FOUND:

Btw, I have not enable billing as I am using the default bucket with the free quota. This is still in development so the free quota works for me.

OK, so I found out where exactly the exception is happening...

byte[] responseBytes = ApiProxy.makeSyncCall(PACKAGE, "GetUrlBase",
           request.build().toByteArray());

and the exception it is throwing is :

ApiProxy.ApplicationException Application Error 8

Enabled billing and tried, still of no use :(

Have been trying to solve this the whole day and tried to search a solution everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Though this actually does not answer my original question but I have found a workaround. I installed python and gsutil and set the default acl of my bucket to read. Now when I am saving an image file in GCS I am just showing the public url link.

The above can also be achieved if in the GCSFileOptions we add .acl("public-read").

Once the acl is applied by either of the above two methods, in the GCS cloud console you can see the images shared publicly link check box comes as a dash and it says you do not have permission to edit permissions. I was getting confused seeing it, as I was expecting the checkbox to be checked.

But even in the above scenario the publicly shared link will work which is:-

[http://storage.googleapis.com/[bucket_name]/[gcs_object_name]](http://storage.googleapis.com/%5bbucket_name%5d/%5bgcs_object_name%5d)

I would still appreciate if someone can explain why the getServingUrl is not not working. Yes, it is still not working after set default acl to read.

Thanks,
Sukalpo.

Answer (score 0):

I could not reproduce this issue by either uploading to Google Cloud storage via the console or via the App Engine GCS Java client. In both cases I could create a public URL for the image
even without specifying any specific permissions.

Do you want to create a production issue request,
https://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/entry?template=Production%20issue
, so we can get more details about your specific case?

Comment: Hi, I donot have the requirement anymore. So right now dont have the resources to follow up with an issue.

Answer (score 0):

What is your gcsPath? I have to use:

```
"/gs/" + gcsFileName.getBucketName() + "/" + gcsFileName.getObjectName();
```

Comment: The requirement changed and I do not have to use the functionality anymore bbut for ur question yes i was using a similar format.

Answer (score 0):

Honestly, the only way I've run into this error (and run into this unsolved question) was when I was accidentally using the **wrong filename in a difficult to notice way** while fetching the BlobKey using Google's APIs.

So, check the obvious things first.