# Creating servingUrl fails: OBJECT_NOT_FOUND?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

My project is running on app engine. I have a servlet that gets a notification, every time a image is uploaded to a certain bucket. Than i retrieve the image data from the bucket, resize it and store it into another bucket. 
Up to this point it all works fine.
Now I want to create a serving url for this image by using a BlobKey. By doing so, I got a error by calling the method:

```
servingUrl = imageService.getServingUrl(ServingUrlOptions.Builder.withBlobKey(bk).secureUrl(true));

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: OBJECT_NOT_FOUND: 
at com.google.appengine.api.images.ImagesServiceImpl.getServingUrl(ImagesServiceImpl.java:282)
at com.google.training.helloworld.ImageTransformHandler.createServingUrlWithBlobkey(ImageTransformHandler.java:51)
at com.google.training.helloworld.Upload.doPost(Upload.java:70)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:637)
at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:717)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHolder.handle(ServletHolder.java:511)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1166)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.ParseBlobUploadFilter.doFilter(ParseBlobUploadFilter.java:125)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.SaveSessionFilter.doFilter(SaveSessionFilter.java:37)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.doFilter(JdbcMySqlConnectionCleanupFilter.java:60)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at com.google.apphosting.utils.servlet.TransactionCleanupFilter.doFilter(TransactionCleanupFilter.java:43)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler$CachedChain.doFilter(ServletHandler.java:1157)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.handle(ServletHandler.java:388)
at org.mortbay.jetty.security.SecurityHandler.handle(SecurityHandler.java:216)
at org.mortbay.jetty.servlet.SessionHandler.handle(SessionHandler.java:182)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.ContextHandler.handle(ContextHandler.java:765)
at org.mortbay.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.handle(WebAppContext.java:418)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.AppVersionHandlerMap.handle(AppVersionHandlerMap.java:260)
at org.mortbay.jetty.handler.HandlerWrapper.handle(HandlerWrapper.java:152)
at org.mortbay.jetty.Server.handle(Server.java:326)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handleRequest(HttpConnection.java:542)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection$RequestHandler.headerComplete(HttpConnection.java:923)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.RpcRequestParser.parseAvailable(RpcRequestParser.java:78)
at org.mortbay.jetty.HttpConnection.handle(HttpConnection.java:404)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.jetty.JettyServletEngineAdapter.serviceRequest(JettyServletEngineAdapter.java:148)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.JavaRuntime$RequestRunnable.run(JavaRuntime.java:468)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.runInContext(TraceContext.java:437)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable$1.run(TraceContext.java:444)
at com.google.tracing.CurrentContext.runInContext(CurrentContext.java:256)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContextNoUnref(TraceContext.java:308)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$AbstractTraceContextCallback.runInInheritedContext(TraceContext.java:300)
at com.google.tracing.TraceContext$TraceContextRunnable.run(TraceContext.java:441)
at com.google.apphosting.runtime.ThreadGroupPool$PoolEntry.run(ThreadGroupPool.java:235)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I checked all my arguments and they are definitely there. Do you have any idea what this error means and how i can fix it?

***EDIT***
my servlet code looks like this. As you can see i wrapped the different google services like gcs in a handler class.

```
UploadObject object             = new UploadObject(notification);
CloudStorageHandler gcs         = new CloudStorageHandler();
BlobstoreHandler bs             = new BlobstoreHandler();
ImageTransformHandler is        = new ImageTransformHandler();

/**GET DATA FROM GCS**/

byte[] data = gcs.getFileFromGoogleCloudStorage(object.getGcsBucket(), object.getGcsPath());

/******************/

/**TRANSFORMATION**/

byte[] newImageData = is.resizePicture(data, 1200, 1200, "JPEG", 65, 0.5, 0.5);

/******************/

/** STORE NEW RESIZED IMAGE IN GCS BUCKET **/

UploadObject tmp = new UploadObject(object.getGcsPath(), "JPEG", "beispiel", 1200, 1200);
tmp.setData(newImageData);
gcs.saveFileToGoogleCloudStorage(newImageData, "beispiel", object.getGcsPath(), "JPEG", "public-read");

/******************/

/** CREATE SERVING URL **/
//BlobKey bk_neu = bs.createBlobKey("beispiel", object.getGcsPath());
//String servingUrl = is.createServingUrlWithBlobkey(bk_neu);
String servingUrl = is.createServingUrlByName(tmp.getGcsBucket(), tmp.getGcsPath());

...
```

Comment: Since your file seems to be in a bucket in Cloud Storage, one might ask why you attempt to create a serving URL using a BlobKey. Why not use `ServingUrlOptions.Builder.withGoogleStorageFileName`?

Comment: as far as i know, the only way to delete a servingUrl is to provide the blobkey. Therefore i want to have it consistent. Besides that 
`ServingUrlOptions.Builder.withGoogleStorageFileName`
returns the same error

Comment: `BlobstoreService.createGsBlobKey()` creates a blob key for any existing or non-existing file in cloud storage. Anyway, since the errors says that the object can't be found it might just be that the object can't be found. Search in the place that creates a blob key for your cloud storage object. It's likely that that's where the problem lies, since *The existance of the file represented by filename is not checked, hence a BlobKey can be created for a file that does not currently exist.* (source: BlobstoreService javadoc) which would explain all symptoms.

Comment: Yes, that might be it. But if i left out the line which creates a serving url. it all works fine. if i look after that insight my storage i can see the resized image.
Is there a way to get a callback or something from my "storeToGcs" method, when the file is successfully stored into the bucket?
Or in another way, how can i check, if a file was added to my bucket beside a notification?

Comment: If by notification you mean this (https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/watchAll) i don't know another mechanism (well except for polling which is generally a bad idea). Of course everything works until you create the serving URL because up until that moment you're basically only configuring your transformer. I'm pretty sure that you're trying to access a non-existent object, could even be that it's a racing of some sort.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OBJECT\_NOT\_FOUND when trying to getServingUrl of an image stored in GCS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23582669/object-not-found-when-trying-to-getservingurl-of-an-image-stored-in-gcs)